# How to move cursor word by word in PhpStorm integrated terminal?

Tags: bash, terminal, phpstorm, caret

I can't use my zsh shortcuts to move the caret by word in PhpStorm's integrated terminal window using i.e. <kbd>⌥</kbd> <kbd>→</kbd> like I use in Terminal App on my Mac.

I have tried to use zsh as shell path in PhpStorm but my default zsh color scheme is not showing well inside of PhpStorm. Seems that also `Mac Terminal->Settings` shortcuts are not being enabled inside PhpStorm terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out that it work only if I bind the shortcuts directly in my `~/.bash_profile`, by adding this at the bottom:

```
bind '"[D": backward-word'
bind '"[C": forward-word'
```

Close all terminal windows inside PhpStorm after making these changes and open the new one.